# Exponential-like function equivalent for the Dixonian Elliptics

Tags: power-series, gamma-function, taylor-series, trigonometric-functions

Is there some exponential-like function that acts as partner for the intricate Dixonian Elliptics, in a similar way that the Exponential function acts as a partner for the trigonometric functions ?

Comment: Are you referring to the functions in https://mathoverflow.net/q/348620/?